# ENVIAR E-MAIL PARA VÁRIOS DESTINATÁRIOS COM O SMTPLIB PYTHON

Tags: python, brasil

estou com um código que envia e-mail para um único destinatário. Agora, eu preciso que esse código:

• ENVIE O E-MAIL PARA VÁRIOS DESTINATÁRIOS AO MESMO TEMPO DE **FORMA ÚNICA**.

**EXEMPLO**: Tenho 20 destinatários, ao invés de escrever um e-mail e colocar esses 20 endereços de e-mail no campo: PARA, eu preciso que o script **envie um único e-mail para essas 20 pessoas, um por um.**

Eu acredito que se eu armazenar os destinatários em uma lista, e fazer o script rodar 20 vezes através de um FOR resolva meu problema, mas não consegui coloca isso em prática. Vocês conseguem me ajudar ? Segue o código abaixo:

```
import smtplib
import email.message

def enviar_email():  
    corpo_email = """
    <p>Prezados, tudo bem?</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>Venho através deste e-mail para notificar ...</p>
    """

    msg = email.message.Message()
    msg['Subject'] = "ASSUNTO" #ASSUNTO DO E-MAIL#
    msg['From'] = 'emailquevaienviar@gmail.com' #E-MAIL QUE VAI ENVIAR O E-MAIL#
    #
    msg['To'] = 'emailquevaireceber@gmail.com'#E-MAIL QUE VAI RECEBER
    password = '123456789' #SENHA DO E-MAIL QUE VAI ENVIAR
    msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    msg.set_payload(corpo_email )

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
    s.starttls()
    # Login Credentials for sending the mail
    s.login(msg['From'], password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string().encode('utf-8'))
    print('Email enviado')
    enviar_email()
```

Comment: Faça loop com for para executar o `s.sendmail()` trocando o `[msg['To']]` pelo endereço que que deseja enviar. PS: não vejo motivo para usar recursão em seu código, um loop com for: já "resolve" para envio para poucas pessoas você poderia simplesmente usar BCC, mas para envio em massa, fazer marketing ou algo assim, a própria ideia vai dar problema, ainda mais que a maioria dos servidores tem limitação de quota, teria que usar um mailer dedicado (tem soluções no mercado pra isso, só não vou sugerir algo porque se não o meu comentário pode soar como "SPAM")

Comment: Gui, como eu posso fazer isso ? Desculpa, mas sou leigo no assunto ainda

Comment: Felipinho, editei o primeiro comment.

Answer (score 1):

caso tente colocar para enviar varios emails, de uma forma que seja 'editavel', eu pensei desta forma, lendo um arquivo txt

```py
def enviar_email(eml):
    
    corpo_email = """
    <p>Mensagem Automática</p>
    """

    
    msg = email.message.Message()
    msg['Subject'] = "msg"
    msg['From'] = 'email'
    msg['To'] = eml
    password = 'senha'
    msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    msg.set_payload(corpo_email)
    


    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    s.starttls()
    s.login(msg['From'], password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string().encode('utf-8'))
    print('Email Enviado')


with open('Email.txt') as file:
    while line := file.readline():
        enviar_email(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

faz o seguinte usa uma lista de emails e faz ele executar o envio para cada 1 como no ex abaixo:

```
import smtplib
import email.message

def enviar_email(email):  
    corpo_email = """
    <p>Prezados, tudo bem?</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>Venho através deste e-mail para notificar ...</p>
    """

    msg = email.message.Message()
    msg['Subject'] = "ASSUNTO" #ASSUNTO DO E-MAIL#
    msg['From'] = 'emailquevaienviar@gmail.com' #E-MAIL QUE VAI ENVIAR O E-MAIL#
    #
    msg['To'] = email #E-MAIL QUE VAI RECEBER
    password = '123456789' #SENHA DO E-MAIL QUE VAI ENVIAR
    msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    msg.set_payload(corpo_email )

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
    s.starttls()
    # Login Credentials for sending the mail
    s.login(msg['From'], password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string().encode('utf-8'))
    print('Email enviado')



lista=['email1@email.com','email2@email.com','email3@email.com']
for email in lista:
    print("enviando email para: ",email)
    enviar_email(email)
```